# Practical difference between definitions of flow?

Tags: graph-theory, definition, network-flow

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3212807/1173386) describes two different definitions of network flow. I'm unable to understand if there's a functional difference between the two. In which minimal cases do the definitions not align for net flow (XOR of definitions is $\emptyset$)?

Comment: The answer in the linked post by Misha Lavrov explains it well. Basically it is two ways of defining the same thing, and one definition can be converted into the other.

Comment: @MathieuRund Is there no separation between the two (XOR = $\emptyset$) in any condition?